# How do I detect back/home press in an accessibility Service?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

The title pretty much sums it up.

I want to detect back/home button press using an Accessibility Service.

It seems that onKeyEvent is not triggered when pressing these buttons.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to detect key events if you create your own *accessibility service*. After that, you need to implement your behavior for the **onKeyEvent()**.

Here is an example:

```
public class AccessibilityKeyDetector extends AccessibilityService  {

...

  @Override
    protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
 // Do your magic
    }

..
}
```

I am assuming that you have checked the accessibility permissions and set the correct configuration of your service.

I hope this code fits you. If you have more doubts, please contact me.

Comment: I tried this. onKeyEvent() never seems to be called. Even when I added this to the accessibility_service_config.xml `android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately onKeyEvent will only get triggered for hardware keys, so  if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) will only get triggered for older phones that have physical back/home buttons. They won't get triggered on newer phones that have the navigation buttons in-screen.